# Making display colors better (TN Panel)

Tags: laptop, display

I just bought Dell Inspiron 7567 and after getting it I realized that it has a TN Panel with really bad colors (almost 300:1 contrast and 65%sRGB) .
So can anyone help me buy giving a icc file or suggesting some other method to make it look better.
I am trying to find an IPS display for it but it will some weeks so I need to make it look better for the being.

Comment: Calibrate it yourself until you are pleased with the results. Each and every panel will be different so only you can know what colour setting suits you best. Also, in most cases, calibrating cannot significantly increase the actual number of colours your display outputs, but good luck. I personally use Lutcurve
Side note: I'm planning to buy the same laptop. The panel isn't a dealbreaker for me. The battery life and ease of maintenance are the deal-makers for this performant laptop.

Comment: can you tell me about any good free software for calibration.
Also I want you to take a look at this laptop display before buying it because its really really bad. I have a dual core laptop from 2010 and even its colors are way better than this crap.

Comment: Notebookcheck oftentimes provide ICC files when they test a laptop. I've found two distinct ones for Inspiron 7567: [this one](https://www.notebookcheck.net/Dell-Inspiron-15-7000-7567-Gaming-i5-7300HQ-GTX-1050-Laptop-Review.239720.0.html) and [that one](https://www.notebookcheck.net/Dell-Inspiron-15-7000-7567-Gaming-Notebook-Review.196454.0.html). (hit `Ctrl`+`F` and search for *ICC*)

Comment: @Faheem : I use the paid Lutcurve for advanced control, but I've found that the one built into Intel Graphics is gets my job done because it also ensures that the colour profiles are loaded properly on boot, which is not always the case with any 3rd party calibration tool. FYI: I checked out the laptop at a store and am satisfied with the colour at a particular viewing angle. As mentioned earlier, we have different requirements, and the display is not a dealbreaker for me.

Answer (score 1):

> 300:1 contrast and 65%sRGB

The sad truth; This is properties set by hardware, and cannot be changed by any software tweak.

Calibration provides an adjustment table so that "small" anomalies in hardware can be tuned to be as close to perfection as possible; compare to straightening a jiggly line, if the "line" has large bends you may be out of luck.

That is: You will NOT get 100% perfection, ever, even using calibration.